# Critique my auth system DB schema?

Tags: database, authentication, schema, authorization

I'm designing a RESTful Web app that will provide an authentication system for several other apps. The other apps will query this app through HTTP and get back XML describing authenticated users.

The authentication app needs to keep track of **which users** are allowed to **do what** on **which applications.**

I'm working out the DB schema. Below is my initial design. (Assume each table has an `id` column.)

```
applications  # The various client apps that will query this auth system.
------------
name

users         # Table simplified for discussion
-----
username
password
email

roles
-----
name
application_id

roles_users
-----------
role_id
user_id
```

The idea is say someone tried to perform an administrative function in the the "Equipment Inventory" app. So "Equipment Inventory" would say to the auth system "get the user with username xxx and password yyy." Then it would look at the returned (via ActiveResource) `User` object and check whether its `roles` Array contains a `Role` with a name of "ADMIN" that itself belongs to an `Application` object with a name of "Equipment Inventory".

Or perhaps it would be better to eliminate the `applications` table and have many more roles, e.g., "`equipment_inventory_admin`", "`equipment_inventory_readonly`", "`job_tracker_admin`", etc.

What's more important, normalizing the Application entity or simplifying the table structure? Perhaps after all that typing I've just answered my own question, but comments or suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema looks sane, 
You would send

`<login><username>abc</username><password>xyz</password><app>51</app></login>`

and you get back

`<auth>
<user>
<username>abc</a>
<lastlogin>123456464</lastlogin>
</user>
<app>
<name>Equipment Inventory</name>
<version>3.1.5e</version>
</app>
<roles>
<role>admin</role>
<role>manager</role>
<role>dataentry</role>
</roles>
</auth>`

or

`<auth><error type="1"></auth>`

Answer (score 1):

Definitely separate authentication from authorization. (looks like you're doing that; the "user" table falls into authentication, the rest + user.id fall into authorization)

Passwords: you're not storing them in the clear, are you? Storing MD5 hashes (+ [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to prevent attacks) would be more secure.

Would [Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/Kerberos/) be a possibility? (perhaps it could be adapted to work over HTTP as a transport layer)

Comment: MD5 hash is no longer considered secure. I'd recommend SHA-256 or SHA-512.

Comment: It is possible at present to find two plaintexts that yield the same MD5 hash, with no preconditions. This has implications for digital signatures. I am not aware of any success where *given* a plaintext, someone can efficiently find another plaintext with a hash collision.

Comment: In any case, adding salt (especially if part of the salt is stored separately from the database in a more secure form) makes it much more intractable to break passwords, since you can't reasonably evaluate password success offline. (forced to use the service in question which is relatively slow)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I tend to err on the side of normalization.  At least in my experience some kind of additional modules get added down the line.  Much easier to add an additional line in application and brand new tables as necessary then editing the existing schema and having to update all relevant Data Access code.

Edit: On a second look you could merge the roles table and the roles_users table.  It could be one place that defines the roles and how the users can access them for each application.

Comment: I wouldn't merge the tables, it's a many-to-many relationship.